# line developers token permission issue

Tags: python, line-api

I use the following simple code to test my line userid and push message.
[image: my code]
I found my line token can't query other person profile and push message to others. It seems to be a token problem. Because i use my friend's token every thing is fine.
Did anyone encounter the same problem?

Many thanks.

Following is my code. by the way the token is real token.(for debug test and Valid for 3 days)

```
    from linebot import LineBotApi
    from linebot.models import TextSendMessage
```

```
line_bot_api = LineBotApi('4gi+D62U0un7Fe9jT5eFOHLaJYzGvYWkRKrLp09oS4nql9opjqKf45hKYYrnZERg1pQeOlIqPFQsZJIAl5YM8xwOFV+TppZUAm4nlDJNbKv+0GjofpP1MnxTG0CJAxpNLFoVoQrgvnLUFhW2bl87kgdB04t89/1O/w1cDnyilFU=')

profile = line_bot_api.get_profile('userid')

print(profile.display_name)
print(profile.user_id)
print(profile.picture_url)
print(profile.status_message)

result = line_bot_api.multicast(['userid1', 'userid2'], TextSendMessage(text='Hello World!'))
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not an image.

Comment: If this code works with an other token, then it might me a good assumption that the token is not valid or not authorized for your actions and the code is OK.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I have posted my code, could you give me some advice?